# Azure function doesn't get executed

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-functions, queue

I'm currently working on an Azure function which should get executed through an Queue-Trigger.
The problem is that it doesn't work as it should.

This is my `__init__.py` file:

```
all imports
...
def main(req: func.QueueMessage, res: func.Out[str]) -> func.QueueMessage:

    print(req)

    cmi_guid = req.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    
    logging.info('Received message: %s', req.get_body().decode('utf-8'))

    logging.info('Received message FULL: %s', req)

    tempFilePath = tempfile.gettempdir()
    print(tempFilePath)

    
    infile = cmi_guid + '.xlsx'
    outfile = cmi_guid + '_output.xlsx'
    local_in_file_path = os.path.join(tempFilePath, infile)
    local_out_file_path = os.path.join(tempFilePath, outfile)

    logging.info('Got temp file path: %s', tempFilePath)

    delete_files(tempFilePath, ".xlsx")
    logging.info('Deleted xlsx files in temp directory')

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(<MyConnectionString>)
    container_name = "cmi"
    # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=infile)

    with open(local_in_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
        download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())

    logging.info('Received input file from blob')

    df_out = start_forecast(local_in_file_path)
    with pd.ExcelWriter(local_out_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:  
        df_out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Forecast', index=False)

    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=outfile)

    try:
        with open(local_out_file_path, "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('Exception when uploading blob: %s', e)

    logging.info('Done uploading blob to storage')
    # res.set(cmi_guid)
    return cmi_guid
```

That is my `function.json`:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "cmi-input",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "name": "res",
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "queueName": "cmi-output",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thats my `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": <MyConnectionString>,
    "MyStorageAccountConnection": <MyConnectionString>
  }
}
```

I have created for every value in the `local.settings.json` an application setting.

When I now upload an file to the cmi-input Queue then the Azure function should actually be started and a file should be loaded into a Blob container (is written in the code).
However, nothing happens.
Have I forgotten any configurations or is it necessary to run them otherwise?

When I'm trying to start the function directly in Visual Studio Code I'm just getting this:
it gets stuck and nothing happens anymore until I stop it...
[message in the Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEyL2.png)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ServiceBusTrigger` needs a Service Bus connection string of the form

```
Endpoint=sb:// ... SharedAccessKeyName ... SharedAccessKey
```

if using shared access keys to connect. `MyConnectionString` is the connection to storage for storing the blob.

You can see the Service Bus connection string in the [Azure python example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python).

Comment: Isn't it possible to set the type as `queueTrigger` that it works?
Because I want that a new message in my queue triggers the function

Comment: the doc that is linked to says "A Service Bus binding is defined in function.json where type is set to serviceBusTrigger" and then you specify the queue in "queueName": "cmi-input"

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand but from where in my code do you see that I need a Service Bus?

Comment: And do I have to create a complete new ServiceBus in the Azure Portal?

Comment: you need an Azure Service Bus Namespace which requires an Azure subscription and appropriate hosting. If someone else has set up the Service Bus namespace you can ask them for the connection string.